# External monitor not working with hdmi - display port adapter

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, monterey, apple-silicon

I have an external LG monitor that I used to use with my previous computer (Macbook Pro 2012) by using a Display Port - Mini Display Port cable.

Recently I got an M1 Macbook Pro (M1 Max chip, running macOS Monterey), and I haven't been able to use my external monitor with that computer. I've tried with an HDMI cable and two different HDMI - Display Port adapters, but the monitor is not receiving any signal. My computer's HDMI port and my HDMI cable  are not the problem, as I've been able to connect it to a TV without issues.

You can therefore understand my confusion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a compatibility problem between hdmi and dvi. DVI to HDMI works with simple adaptateur due to HDMI TDMS compatibility mode. The other direction is not possible without specific IP encoder. Be careful as trying to plus DVI screen on HDMI port may cause damage.

Comment: More info [here](https://www.tempest-av.com/single-post/2019/02/07/HDMI-to-DisplayPort-and-DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Conversion-Explained)

Comment: Thanks @PtitXav, this answers my question.I guess my options are then to either get an active adapter, get a DP-Thunderbolt adapter, or get a monitor with an HDMI input.